# Are sockets integrated into the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, sockets

Have the new C++ standards implemented a common way of handling sockets? In 2010 I know the standarization of threading was implemented in vs2k10 (C++0x later C++11). C++14 is knocking on the door.

I would hate to come back to still dealing with Winsock and regular Linux sockets. Compared to more modern languages, such as C# or java, they were also harder to use.

Comment: There is a study group, [SG4 Networking](https://github.com/SG4/draft/wiki), under WG21 (The ISO C++ committee) working on stuff like networking related libraries, including sockets and HTTP. Whether it eventually will be part of the standard is impossible to say.

Comment: @mebob: He's close to correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the fact that he is "close to correct" but off by that tiny bit is what shows the lack of research. I mean, a simple Google search and two clicks and he could find out it is C++11. Also, a simple Google search can find if sockets are in C++. A better question would be "Will C++ have networking at some point" or something similar, since that is what it seems like he is really asking.

Comment: @mebob "Will C++ have networking at some point" is OT for this site however

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, I'm aware. The problem I see is that he is asking indefinitely by asking a question that is easily answerable with a Google search. He did fix the other issues though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are sockets integrated into the c++ standard

No.

Sockets are a part of the Posix and Winsock standards, not the C or C++ standard.

NB 'Non-JIT languages' have nothing to do with it.

Comment: You only answered a small part of the question. _"Do anyone know of plans of a roadmap for further development of the standard?"_ Can't see why this is accepted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You know perfectly well that I answered more, although not to your liking, as you edited it out, not to mention other occurrences in this thread. Don't start all that again, unless you provide your address for service of notices.

Comment: (a) You did not address further development of the standard in any revision of your answer, so I don't see why you need to bring all that back up again. It is not relevant. (b) Service of notices? What are you talking about now? Are you threatening me with some sort of legal action?! Lol...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And I was not clear enough in my question, I should have said c/c++. Pardon me but I am new to this site.

Answer (score 8):

The Networking TS expected to be part of C++17 standard is based on Boost.ASIO, so for now u might want to use Boost.ASIO

Comment: This didn't age well

Answer (score 1):

not in c++(20), yet...

But there has been movement in the last years. Technical specifications, Drafts, conference talks...

There‘s an article by 
[Vinnie Falco](https://github.com/vinniefalco) ( developer of boost::beast and active c++ evangelist) 
 on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/b12iob/networking_ts_beast_new_tutorials_read_this_to/)

- [socket.h in gcc (experimental)](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/socket)
- [working draft](https://cplusplus.github.io/networking-ts/draft.pdf)
- [experimental included in libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2018-10/msg00740.html)
- [2019: Suggestion to the c++ committee to include it in c++2020](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1446r0.html)